# C++ code error assignment

Tags: c++

**I have a question on my assignment that tells me**

If a certain character is  a number , it must be transformed to another character whose value equals the remainder of original number n division by 4 (n%4). For example if the user inputs  “987654” , the output ( after taking the remainder and reversing the array) should be :  “012301” .

**The code i've written works well very much except for this part i want to take the remainder in my function but it doesn't seem to work at all any suggestions ?**

```
void function(char x[], int size)
{

        **if (x[i] >= '0' && x[i] <= '9')
        {
            x[i]=x[i] % 4;
        }**
        cout << x[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}


}
```

Comment: You're confusing digits (which are characters) with numbers. The character `'0'` is not represented by the number zero.

Comment: even when i type x>0 and x<0 it  takes the statement as if it is false

Comment: it doesn't take any remainders just prints it in reverse

Comment: It's a bit confusing that your code seems to do more than what your question asks about - it changes the case of letters and reverses the string. Can you edit your question so that the text and the code are more consistent, perhaps focussing only on the bit you're having difficulty with? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array x contains characters but in the section you highlighted, the transformation relies on finding the integer value `n` represented by that digit character `x[i]`.

Luckily, since the ASCII value representing `'0'` character is divisible by `4`, even if you do not subtract the value of '`0'` from `x[i]`, the outcome of the modulus operation is not affected. Nonetheless, after finding the modulo 4 of `n`, you end up with an integer value in the range [0, 4). To reflect that back to the string, as a character, you need to add back the integer value of `'0'` to it.

Below is a code sample demonstrating what I mentioned above.

```
if (x[i] >= '0' && x[i] <= '9')
{
    int n = (x[i] - '0');
    x[i] = (n % 4) + '0';
}
```

Comment: Thank you it seems like it worked but i really don't understand what u did there so much i know that zero has an ascii code of 48 , do u mean that 0 has 48 and 1 has 49 so 49-48 leaves us out with 1  ?

Comment: You're welcome @MohammedMaGdy . If you think I answered your question properly, remember to mark my answer as the answer to your question. Also, you really should read more on concepts such as "ASCII encoding", or converting integers to strings.

Comment: @Mohammed - Your code `if (x[i] >= '0' && x[i] <= '9')` already assumed that characters representing digits are in order (which is true, and not only for ASCII). ilim is then using that knowledge.